# how do I fix this ant design datepicker component in my react project .I have shared a screenshot

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project which required ant design datepicker along with bootstrap.I'm not sure whats making this **datepicker** move out of screen. Is there something I need to do with bootstrap classes to fix this? I have shared my screenshot.thanenter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ1uv.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ1uv.jpg)

```
const form= () => (
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block m-3">Add image
                    <input type="file" name="image" onChange={handleImageChange} accept="image/*" hidden/>
                </label>

                <input className="form-control m-2" type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" onChange={handleChange} value={title}/>
                <textarea className="form-control m-2" type="text" name="content" placeholder="content" onChange={handleChange} value={content}/>
                <AlgoliaPlaces className="form-control ml-2" placeholder="location" defaultValue={location} options={config} onChange={handleSearch} style={{height:"50px"}} />
                <input className="form-control m-2" type="number" name="price" placeholder="price" onChange={handleChange} value={price}/>
                <input className="form-control m-2" type="number" name="bed" placeholder="Number of beds" onChange={handleChange} value={bed}/>
            </div>  
            **<DatePicker className="form-control m-2"/>** 
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary m-2">Add</button>
        </form>
    )
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="container-fluid p-5 text-center">
                <h2>Add </h2>
            </div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        {hotelForm()}
                    </div
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <img src={preview} alt="preview-image" className="img img-fluid m-2" />
                        <pre>{JSON.stringify(values,null, 2)}</pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Working example in codesandox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing ant design css stylesheet.

Try to add the following line at the root of your app :

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```